# image segmentation for connected character in morphology

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

before i asked a same similar question,i tried using a watershed to segmentation the connected character but it does not well.a weeks ago,i get same question at stackoverflow in google search,[Segmentation for connected characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211413/segmentation-for-connected-characters),
in the answer users,the author **mmgp** provide a solution that use a morphology method and closing operation but i not understand all.

i just thinning a image in hit-and-miss morphology.

[image] 
the original image

[image]   the thinning image [image] the big image for the thinning image (enlarge)

the 4-connectivity can split a digit **9** to individual character but **44** still connected.

i have a some of question about [Segmentation for connected characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211413/segmentation-for-connected-characters)

**1.why need resize the original image to 200-pixel and then thinning it.**

why not thinning the original image by immediate.

**2.how extract these branch points and apply a  morphological closing  to thinning image.**

i just know the closing morphology is a **erosion** and **dilation** combine operation.

the closing's vertical line need a 2*height+1(this a structure element height?),i don't know and how setting.the structure element how to constructre(3*3 or other?).

the finally they get a following image

[image]

i need some help, someone can tell me how apply closing operation and get above a image.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this problem use a foreground-feature and background-feature.

some of people that details about this algorithm below:

Agenetic framework using contextual knowledge for segmentation and recognition of handwritten numeral strings

Segmentation of Handwritten Numeral Strings in Farsi and English Languages.

the flowing image is my capture.

foreground-region and foreground-skeleton

[image]
[image]

background-region and background-skeleton

[image]
[image]

the skeleton image for 44.

[image]

based on the above feature-points ,we can constructing a segmentation path to split 449 digit.

Comment: Nice. I just read the paper. Do you understand how does the author get background region (white pixel outside of the black object)? I don't understand what he meant here. Btw, how do you extract the top and bottom? Hope to hear from you @zhengchun

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method for closing operation:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(2*h+1,1))
closed_img = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```