# opencv segment conntected characters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to do character detect for handwriting letters.

Upon recognizing itself, I use tesseract or opencv SVM, and works fine till now.

Everything works fine for segment letters until I hit those connected ones.

I use the following code to segment letters:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cv2
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from os.path import dirname, join, basename
import sys
from glob import glob

trainpic=[]
targetdir = dirname(__file__)+'tmporigin'
#print glob(join(dirname(__file__)+'/cat','*.jpg'))
img = {}

debug = True
a_num = 0
for fn in glob(join(targetdir, '*')):
    filename = basename(fn)
    trainpic.append(cv2.imread(fn, 0))
    img_rgb = cv2.imread(fn)
    img = cv2.imread(fn, 0)
    image_close = cv2.morphologyEx(img_rgb, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((1, 7), np.uint8))
    #if debug:
    #    cv2.imshow('morphology', image_close)
    #    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    samples = np.empty((0, 100))
    responses = []
    # keys = [i for i in range(48, 58)]
    tmp_list = []
    tmpcount = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        print 'contourarea:%s' % cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 130:  # 50 300
            [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            print 'boundingRect width:%s' % w
            print 'boundingRect height:%s' % h
            if h > 28:
                cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                roismall = cv2.resize(roi, (45, 55))
                if debug:
                    cv2.imshow('norm', img_rgb)
                    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
                # tmp_list.append(roi)
                tmpfilename = fn if tmpcount == 0 else fn.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '_' + str(tmpcount) + '.png'
                cv2.imwrite(tmpfilename, roismall)
                tmpcount += 1
        else:
            print 'contarea less, skip...'

    #    print img[num].shape
    a_num += 1

print '%s images processed' % a_num
```

So, its fine to handle letters with inter space like this guy(split to D and B):

[image]

However, failed to segment connected letters like this:

[image]

I googled a lot for connected letters and find related links like these two:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194103/connected-character-segmentation-in-opencv)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211413/segmentation-for-connected-characters)

I tried a lot, e.g. morphology dilate, erode, open, close, watershed .etc but didn't fix my problem.

I use opencv 3.2.0 and python 2.7.10 upon my Ubuntu desktop.

Any suggestion is great appreciated.

Thanks.

Wesley

Comment: Did you read [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=E6122958EB8D16F13E0EEC460D6207E5?doi=10.1.1.308.445&rep=rep1&type=pdf)? Might provide some leads (esp. 4.1).

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, I read the doc but didn't get any more useful information, words in the doc is too general. I am trying to read tesseract source code, hope to find something